# remove existing div and append to new div on load using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a set of div's

```
<div id="foo">foo</div>
<div id="q"></div>
<div id="bar">bar</div>
<div id="tags">tags</div>
```

i need to remove `<div id="tags">tags</div>`  and append it to `<div id="q"></div>` when the page is loaded using jquery.

i tried the below but doesnt work

```
jQuery(function ($) {

 $( '#tags' ).ready(function() {
        $('#q').append(this);

    });


});
```

instead of ready if y try click it works but i need to show it when the page is loaded

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this : You can use `appendTo()` or `append()` as shown below

1) appendTo()

```
$(function() {
   $('#tags').appendTo('#q');
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ygcx972y/4/)**

2) append()

```
$(function() {
   $('#q').append($('#tags'));
});
```

**[JSfiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ygcx972y/6/)**

**NOTE** - make sure that `id`s of the elements are unique through out the DOM

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     var ele= $('#tags').html();
     $('#tags').remove();
     $('#q').append(ele);
 });
```